# Convert 1 form of emoticon in other form

Tags: utf-8, python-3.6, emoticons, nsutf8encoding

I am extracting a tweet from twitter which has an emoticon in it using **python** and storing it in csv file. The emoticon is represented in "**\ud83d\ude01**" form. I want to convert it into **Unicode** format (**U+1F603**), how to convert it??

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The emoticon is "grinning face with big eyes"

Comment: U+1F603 is not UTF-8. It's the Unicode code point. The UTF-8 representation of it is `F0 9F 98 83`.

Comment: You want to store the string "U+1F603" in your CSV? Why? That probably doesn't do you any good.

Comment: I've stored the tweet, I want to extract emoticon from tweet and classify it by comparing it with unicode and display the description

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I'm sure you'll find help here, but you need to describe what you ultimately want to do, and where you are stuck specifically.

Comment: The "U+1F603" format is for discussion purposes, not storage, processing or presentation purposes.